# How do i fill the missing part in this picture using OpenCV (python)?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

[I have to generate a new image such that the missing portion of the black ring is shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUSS0.png)

[For Example, consider this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuIq2.png)

[As we can see , a sector of the inner black ring is missing, and my task is to identify
where to fill in. I have to take a plain white image of same dimensions as the input image and predict
(marked by black color) the pixels that i’ll fill in to complete the black outer ring. A
pictorial representation of the output image is as follows:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebONv.png)

Please help me out...i'm new to OpenCV so please explain me the steps as detailed as possible.I am working in python, so i insist on a python solution for the above problem

Comment: Compare the image to a perfect one, pixel by pixel.

Comment: No, i can't do it that way..it explicitly says "This is not a machine learning task. This could be easily solved using simple
image processing concepts."

Comment: Are you addressing me ?

Comment: Yes @YvesDaoust

Comment: Where do you see machine learning in what I said ? This is elementary image processing.

Comment: actually, i meant to say that i don't have a perfect image

Comment: Doesn't seem difficult to create one by replicating some sector. But you actually tell us tool little of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can find a white object (sector) whose centroid is at the maximum distance from the center of the picture.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 

img = cv2.imread('JUSS0.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
w,h=gray.shape
thresh=cv2.threshold(gray, 253, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY )[1]
output = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(thresh, 4, cv2.CV_32S)
num_labels = output[0]
labels = output[1]
centroids = output[3]
polar_centroids_sq=[]
for i in range(num_labels):
    polar_centroids_sq.append((centroids[i][0]-w/2)**2+(centroids[i][1]-h/2)**2)
idx=polar_centroids_sq.index(max(polar_centroids_sq))  
out=np.uint8(255*(labels==idx))    

cv2.imshow('sector', out)
cv2.imwrite('sector.png', out)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I like the idea myself, but my code is not good enough..

Answer (score 0):

This is one of many possible approaches.

- make every pixel that is not black into white, so your image is black and white. This means your processing is simpler, uses less memory and has only 1 channel to process instead of 3. You can do this with `cvtColor()` to get greyscale and then `cv2.threshold()` to get pure black and white.
- repeatedly construct (imaginary) radial lines until, when checking the pixels along the lines, you have 2 black stretches. You now have the inner and outer radius of the inner, incomplete circle. You can get the coordinates of points along a line with **scikit-image** [line function](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.draw.html#skimage.draw.line/).
- draw that circle in full in black with `cv2.circle()`
- subtract that image from your initial black and white image so that only the differences (missing part) shows up in the result.

Of course, if you already know the inner and outer radius of the incomplete black ring, you can completely omit the second step above and do what Yves suggested in the comments.

Or, instead of second step above, run edge detection and HoughCircles to get the radii.

---

Another approach might be to call `cv2.warpPolar()` to convert your circular image to a long horizontal one with 2 thick black lines, one of them discontinuous. Then just draw that line across the full width of the image and warp back to a circle.

Comment: I implemented a solution using HoughCircles but i was facing an issue. I don't know why HoughCircles wasn't working (i was getting output as None). Nevermind , i just calculated the radius and radius thickness and eyeballed cv2.circle() function to match it with the perfect ring shape.Then i just used logical X-OR of this image with the original one(tthresholded one) to get my desired output. Is it cheating XD?

Comment: Thank's for the help Yves Daoust and Mark Setchell. Really appreciate it.